# jQuery селекторы - Обращение к динамически подгружаемым тегам

Tags: jquery, php

Вот есть у меня страница, через jQuery ajax-ом подгружается ещё одна страница, но скрипт jQuery на первой не видит теги, которые подгрузились, как это сделать?.. Вариант скрипта на подгруженной странице не катит, ибо работать надо с первой, но с учётом второй

**Добавлено.**

Код подгружаемой страницы:

```
<?php  
    include('config.php');  
    include('data.php');  
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251');  
    init();  
    Opros();  
?>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".obtn").click(
    function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'opros.php?ans=' + $(this).html(),
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#opros").html("Loading..");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#opros").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

На главной есть Div, в который это всё впихивается

```
if ($("#opros").length) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'opros.php',
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#opros").html("Loading..");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#opros").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

этим скриптом

Comment: ну так и приведите код этих страниц. 

Comment: Посмотреть бы как это вы делаете, чтобы что-то вам советовать, потому что не должно быть проблем с доступом к элементам загруженной страницы

Comment: и задача $(".obtn").click сделать на главной странице, но  $(".obtn") не находится

Comment: @Sleepless Избегайте добавления объемного кода в комментарии. Правильно редактировать исходный вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(".obtn").click( … ) // такая конструкция работает только с теми элементами, которые созданы на момент выполнения этой строки.
 $(".obtn").live("click", function(){ … }) // а вот такая уже работает и с теми, которые созданы позже, в том числе подгружены аяксом.
 $(".obtn").on("click", function() { … }) // а вот так положено писать с jquery версии 1.7.1 и новее.
```